# dask switch columns values when select subset of existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have dataframe which I read with dask. If I read original dataframe it looks like this:

```
df=dd.read_csv('table/short_table.csv')

df.compute()

>>> Unnamed: 0     val1     val2   crop        val_int   val_3   val_4   y
0      0          -18.23    0.34   soybeans     14.0     0.32     0.11   0.55
1      1          -18.92    0.33   oranges      14.0     0.12     0.87   0.62
2      2          -18.11    0.22   cotton       14.0     0.44     0.12   0.43
...
```

I have tried to take only subset of that dataframe,but for some reason it takes wrong columns :

```
df=df[['crop','val_int','val1','val2','y']]
df.compute()

 
>>> crop     val_int  val1       val2    y
    -18.23    14.0    soybenas   0.55   0.34
    -18.92    14.0    oranges    0.62   0.33
    -18.11    14.0    cotton     0.43   0.22
```

I have reset the kernel and every time when I run it it takes wrong values , sometimes in different order (like it mismtach different columns).
I could not find any reason for this phenomenon, why would it change the values? is there any way to get the correct columns with correct values?

Comment: Looks highly unusual, but also there might be some code that was not included that modifies the dataframe...

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev there is no more code beside what I post here

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, the columns don't match on names (`int_val` vs `val_int`; `val_1` vs `val1`, etc.). So it's either referring to two different files/dataframes or some code is missing (transforming/renaming columns, etc.).

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev sorry,this is because I tried to mimic the results I get. I'll fix it now

Comment: Can I ask what version of Dask you are using? There was a very similar sounding issue a few months ago which has since been fixed (detailed [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7759)).

Does upgrading Dask fix the issue?